# Azure-Web-sites: How to cancel a deployment?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-powershell, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function App / Azure Website setup with continuous deployment from source-control.

This App has a custom deployment script that takes quite a bit of time to run. Occasionally I push out a change to git which was a mistake, and I want to cancel that one deployment (While still allowing future git pushes to cause a deployment).

Is there a PowerShell command I can run, or some option which will cancel my current deployment?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to figure this out eventually, and figured I'd post it here. There is no "clean" way to do this, but there is a "hack".

1. Navigate to your SCM site:

   [YOUR_WEBSITE].scm.azurewebsites.net
2. Click on "Process Explorer"
3. Find the process which is the current deployment and choose "Properties".
4. Scroll to the bottom of the page and choose "Kill"

Voilà, you've killed your deployment in the middle.

Comment: Wallah -> voila.  It means "there it is" in French.

Comment: for linux machines, process explorer is disabled. tried running azure cli commands but didnt help. My deployment seems to have gotten stuck at npm install and I am not able to stop it. Even a redeploy is queued.

Answer (score 8):

Just run this small az-cli command. It will stop/kill your current deployment.

`az webapp deployment source delete --name MyWebApp --resource-group MyResourceGroup`

Once it's done, you can try deploying your webapp again!

Comment: Thanks @sandeep - this is my "go to" answer on this page and it works flawlessly every time.

Comment: Will this affect any DNS settings ?

Comment: @0xD1x0n It wont affect any DNS Settings

Comment: Thx! That helped! (linux app, python)

Comment: Worked for Node.js Linux app.

Comment: Does also work for Azure Function Apps; just replace 'webapp' with 'functionapp' (my deployment from Visual Studio was on 'pending' for ages. After I ran the above command, the deployment finally 'failed' and I was able to redeploy.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to stop the web app.
Open the webapp in Azure portal
Click on Stop or Restart

This will stop active deployments,
Redeploy from VS Code.

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers here helped me (Azure Web App deployment on Linux service plan), my deployment was just stuck at the `"Zip package size: x.xx MB"` message, while the deployment logs said it was stuck at "Detecting platforms..."

What did work for me was:

1. Using the Kudu web interface (yourappname.scm.azurewebsites.net) to open a bash shell. I browsed to the site/locks/deployment directory and viewed the lock file:

`~/site/locks/deployment$ cat info.lock`

2. It said the deployment lock was there until c.25 mins after I started the deployment, which was too long for me to wait (impatient).

`"lockExpiry":"2023-03-10T22:55:31.1607086Z"`

3. So:

`rm info.lock`

4. And then restart the azure web app.
5. I was then able to start a new deployment which went through perfectly fine.

Hope this helps others.

Comment: Just had the same issue (don't know why the CLI was stuck), and follow the same method on my Linux App works fine!

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing simple as far as I know.

It's possible that deleting the deployment via kudu rest apis (https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API#deployment) would achieve what you want, but I expect that that will fail during deployment / only delete metadata and logs about the deployment.

Also, cancelling a deployment could leave unwanted artifacts in the filesystem / corrupt your web app. It's probably best to modify your deployments so that you have a development branch and a release branch in order to set up a more robust CI scenario.

Comment: Manson - I'm working on some custom deployment scripts, this is not production stuff (Yet). In any case, I'll give it a shot, but I think you're correct that will only delete the logs.