# Force stop Azure App Service Deployment Slot Swap

Tags: azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment-slots, azure-web-app-for-containers

We are using Azure DevOps to deploy to a staging slot and then swap with production.
When there is an issue swapping it will keep trying for nearly 30 minutes.

Therefore I would like to put a timeout on the swap task, but if I do that it will stop the task in DevOps and leave the process happening in Azure.

I would like a way to force stop the process through a CLI, API, PowerShell or DevOps task.

Azure CLI doesn't seem to have anything
Kudu API can delete deployments but doesn't look to stop them (https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API#deployment)

I have read that you can stop a process, but using a Linux Container App Service, I can't see that option. [Azure-Web-sites: How to cancel a deployment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41965933/azure-web-sites-how-to-cancel-a-deployment)

Is there a way?

Comment: Can the solution in this [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59966577/is-it-possible-to-do-swap-start-stop-slots-in-cloud-service-classic-on-azure) solve your issue?

Comment: @WalterQian-MSFT I do not think it will as it would be restricted to the Start/Stop etc commands, which when running the Stop I get an error that an operation is still in progress. Further to that the Stop command stops the slot, which I don't want to do. I just want to force cancel the deployment.

Answer (score 0):

## Update

> [If any errors occur in the target slot (for example, the production slot) after a slot swap, restore the slots to their pre-swap states by swapping the same two slots immediately](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots#roll-back-a-swap).

[image]

So, we don't need to stop it, just wait swap operation succeed.

> When you submit swap slot request, you will get HttpStatus 202 code. On portal, when you click swap button, you will find that the browser has been requesting the url of location to get the status of swap.

**As for when it ends, we can check the swap operation by polling.**

If the swap operation time is too long, it is recommended to raise a support ticket and ask the engineer to check the reason.

## Previous

You can use `AzureAppServiceManage` task.

[Azure App Service Manage task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-app-service-manage?view=azure-devops)

> Use this task to start, stop, restart, slot swap, Swap with Preview, install site extensions, or enable continuous monitoring for an Azure App Service.

## Tips

When you use rest api to swap slot, you can check `location` in response header.

[image]

When you submit swap slot request, you will get HttpStatus `202` code. On portal, when you click swap button, you will find that the browser has been requesting the url of location to get the status of swap.

Comment: This can start the swap, stop the app service, but it can't stop the swap. Even when you go to the Portal and select Complete Swap it errors with another operation is in progress. I need a method to interupt this can force cancel the swap

Comment: Thank you for the update. However, the aim is to not wait for the operation to fail. This can wait for a long time so I want to interupt it.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use the following command in Azure PowerShell task to cancel a pending swap:

```
Invoke-AzResourceAction -ResourceGroupName [resource group name] -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/slots -ResourceName [app name]/[slot name] -Action resetSlotConfig -ApiVersion 2015-07-01
```

Here is the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots#cancel-a-pending-swap-swap-with-review-and-restore-the-source-slot-configuration) and my sample, I added `-Force -Confirm:$false` at the end of the command:
[image]

Comment: Hello, I still get 'Cannot modify this site because another operation is in progress.'

```
Connect-AzAccount
Set-AzContext -Subscription "***"
Invoke-AzResourceAction -ResourceGroupName $rgName -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/slots -ResourceName $appName/$slotName -Action resetSlotConfig -ApiVersion 2015-07-01 -Force -Confirm:$false
```